# Spring : allowableValues return customize message?

Tags: java, spring

I use `allowableValues` in my Spring project, but if user does not enter allowed values, it's returning "Internal Error".

How can I return the allowable values in the returned error message ?

Comment: use an interceptor!

Comment: hi, is it normal it returns "internal error" ?  why interceptor will help ?

Comment: You said *How can I return the allowable values in the returned error message* which mean you want a specific error message based on the real error